# Using a parameter with exec in Ruby

Tags: ruby, bash

I'm trying to execute the command exec when I give it a parameter by console, but I don´t know how to make it.

```
exec('ls -l #{argv[1]}')
```

Argv[1] is the parameter I pass by console but it doesn´t do anything.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: You need to use double quotes when interpolating into a string: `exec("ls -l #{argv[1]}")`

Answer (score 2):

Unless you need your command to be executed by a shell (such as, you redirect to/from a file), you can pass a list of arguments to `exec`:

```
exec 'ls', '-l', ARGV[1]
```

You're aware that `exec` **replaces** the running ruby process? Do you want `system` instead?

https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.0/Process.html#method-c-exec
https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.0/Kernel.html#method-i-system

Answer (score 0):

There are several small issues in your code:

- variables are not interpolated in [single-quote strings](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.0/doc/syntax/literals_rdoc.html#label-Strings); this means your script always tries to execute `ls -l #{argv[1]}` (as it is written here).
- there is no variable, constant or method of class `Object` that is named `argv`; there is a [global constant named `ARGV`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.0/doc/globals_rdoc.html) that contains the command line arguments.
- [`ARGV`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.0/doc/globals_rdoc.html) does not contain the script name (it is stored in a separate property) but only its positional parameters; consequently, the first argument in the command line is stored at index `0`, not `1`.

Putting together all of the above, your script should be:

```
exec("ls -l #{ARGV[0]}")
```

Comment: Nitpicking: `ARGV` is a global _constant_, not a variable.

Comment: Arguably, it's a variable that gets initialize very early (but is not hard-coded, as it can change from run to run.)

Comment: @axiac you gotta be kidding: `ARGV` is in [predefined **global constants** section](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.0/doc/globals_rdoc.html#label-Pre-defined+global+constants).

Comment: @chepner not arguably at all: anything having a name starting with an uppercase is a constant in ruby, period.

Comment: @mudasobwa you're right. It seems I missed the intermediate section headers. I corrected the answer.